# Cannot provide paypal buy now custom shipping rate

Tags: html, paypal

I'm using a Paypal BuyNow button, and I can't for the life of me get my custom shipping values passed along with the form. Its always overridden by the value in the saved button, or in the shipping calculator. My shipping values are too complicated to be handled through paypals calculator, and they need to be calculated server side and passed along via the buy now form.

In 'my saved button', I have the option enabled: Use settings saved in your Paypal profile

In my shipping calculator preferences, I have two shipping options, both of them enabled: Use settings saved in your Paypal profile

I have some values in the calculator because otherwise paypal always defaults shipping to 0.

Finally in my form, I have

```
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="3.99">
```

For the life of me I cannot get this value to be passed along. I've changed the name to shipping1, handling_cart, shipping_1, every time it seems to be ignored. I have zero problems with google checkout receiving this value. What could possibly be causing paypal to ignore my value? Their support has been useless.

Comment: The answer was that you cannot use paypal 'Hosted' buy now buttons, you need to recreate the button and uncheck save this button as well as remove encryption once its done. Terrible

Comment: Are you sure? From PayPal, "...shipping rates you set up in your Profile take priority over values specified with this variable, unless you select the *Override shipping methods per transaction* checkboxes in the shipping methods you defined..."

Comment: Yes, with hosted buttons you can't override this via HTML params, because hosted buttons are meant to prevent exactly that

Answer (score 0):

on the postage calculations page there is an option

Click here to allow transaction-based postage values to override the profile postage settings listed 
above (if profile settings are enabled).

tick that and you should have more luck.

I was having the exact same issue ...